# Terraform v0.13.3 : Getting Error : Error: Failed getting task definition ClientException: Unable to describe task definition. "wordpress"

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, terraform, cluster-computing, amazon-ecs

my terraform code looks like below for task definition of resource

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "wordpress" {
family                = "wordpress"
container_definitions = <<DEFINITION
```

[

When i run **terraform plan** command to execute my ECS cluster  it is giving error as below
**Error: Failed getting task definition ClientException: Unable to describe task definition. "wordpress"**

Do you have any insights for this to resolve?... THANKS

Comment: Realized how to resolve this issue .Below is my code to fix this issue

Comment: data "aws_ecs_task_definition" "wordpress" {
  task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.wordpress.family
  depends_on      = [aws_ecs_task_definition.wordpress]
}

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone runs into this and the `depends_on` workaround doesn't work:

In my case, it was a leftover artifact in the terraform state after renaming a resource without waiting for the dependencies to be properly deleted. I resolved it by listing all resources in the state:

```bash
terraform state list
```

and then removing the old resource name

```bash
terraform state rm <resource_name>
```

I hope this helps!